# Microphone no longer works in Skype

Tags: audio, microphone, skype

I tried going into System Preferences, Sound, and Input and making sure the "Internal Microphone" is highlighted but it still won't work. No one can hear me in any Skype calls I make.

Comment: Make sure the "Input volume" in the pref pane is turned up.  If the microphone is working, you should see the little blue bars next to "Input level" light up when you speak.

Comment: Hello, @haley. More details will be helpful. What Mac and OS version do you have? Does the microphone work in other applications?

Comment: Have you tried restarting? Sometimes my computer has trouble finding the camera (although the microphone works), and I have always been able to get it back by restarting.

Comment: I think we may have a drive-by question here; the questioner hasn't been back here since asking the question.

Comment: @Neil 9 hrs isn't that long. I expect that, like many folks, this user (new to Stack Exchange) is used to other forums where replies take much longer than here. I'm sure he'll be back before long.

Comment: @Nathan - Certainly, but have a look at [the original edit of the question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/13675/revisions). The user was frantic to have this fixed.

Comment: @Neil I certainly remember the original ;)! Just another reason I expect him to pop up again. Unless, of course, one of the comments fixed it and he hasn't been back since (0_0).

Answer (score 2):

Skype uses a separate audio configuration that can be different from the main system configuration. Go to Skype Preferences, then "Audio/Video", and check the settings there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Skype is actually installed: don’t run Skype from the download image.